# AnyLogic - Place Agents in Point Node Collection

Tags: anylogic, agent

I created a network consisting of paths and point nodes. Some of the nodes are part of an arraylist collection with the element type PointNode. On model startup I generate a population of agents with the number of agents equal to the size of the collection of point nodes.

I now want set the agents location so that each point node of the collection contains exactly one newly created agent. What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. In case anyone else is wondering:
On model startup the following code is executed in the main agent:

```
//set locations for agents
for (int j=0; j< agents.size(); j++)
    {
        agents(j).location = collectionOfPointNodes.get(j);
        agents(j).jumpTo(agents(j).location);
    }
```